# WSO2 APIM iframe options

Tags: iframe, wso2, wso2-api-manager

We'd like to promote some exposed APIs from the API manager on a different portal. The APIM Store even has an "Embed" button on the API overview providing an HTML snippet to include an iframe code into the page (refering the /store/apis/widget page).

However - the widget (and according my experience - any response) of the APIM store includes the "X-Frame-Options" set to DENY, effectviely prohibiting use of iframe.

Is there any way to allow the widget into an iframe?

Edit: seeing following post -
 I have feeling that I won't be able to anything about the X-Frame-Options header ( https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/Security+Advisory+WSO2-2016-0092 ), we could remove the header on the proxy server level, but I woudn't like to compromise security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display store jaggery app within an IFrame, you need to modify the 'jaggery.conf' file located in the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/` directory. There you have to add antiClickJackingOption and antiClickJackingUri(URI that should be allowed) [related parameters](http://www.jobtrolley.com/docs/config/filter.html#HTTP_Header_Security_Filter/Initialisation_parameters) into the security filters section as below.

```
"filters":[
       {
            "name":"HttpHeaderSecurityFilter",
            "class":"org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter",
            "params" : [
                      {"name" : "hstsEnabled", "value" : "false"},
        {"name" : "antiClickJackingEnabled", "value" : "true"},
        {"name" : "antiClickJackingOption", "value" : "ALLOW-FROM"},
        {"name" : "antiClickJackingUri", "value" : "http://napagoda.com/*"},
        {"name" : "blockContentTypeSniffingEnabled", "value" : "false"}
            ]
        },
```